# axios go in catch function instead of then, if status is 302

Tags: node.js, mongodb, axios

I am saving data to mongodb with create function, after successfully data saved to database, i am sending message with 302 status code. But axios going in catch function instead of then function. And response is undefined.But when i see the response in network tab.I am getting the response.Below is my code.

**saving data in mongodb**

```
exports.addProject = async (req, res) => {
  Project.create(req.body)
    .then(function(){
      res.status(302).send({message: MESSAGE.PROJECT_ADDED_SUCCESS})
    })
   .catch(err => handleErrors(res, err));
};
```

**At fronend, in axios, while getting response**

```
export function addProject(data) {
const token = localStorage.getItem(CONFIG.AUTH_TOKEN);
const url = `${CONFIG.API_BASE_URL}/api/projects`;
    axios.post(url, data, { headers:{ Authorization:`${token}`}}).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    })
    .catch(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    })
}
```

Please tell me how can i get response in axios request then function. Below is the attached error image. [image: error image]

Comment: but why are you serving response with status 302 (Found status, which must contain Location header aka redirect)? If yore creating a resource you might want to use status 201 (Created).
[Read this](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/396#issuecomment-395592900)

Comment: are you trying to redirect your app on success of axios post call ?

Comment: no, I just want to get the response.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the option `validateStatus`

This is the default value

```
// `validateStatus` defines whether to resolve or reject the promise for a given
// HTTP response status code. If `validateStatus` returns `true` (or is set to `null`
// or `undefined`), the promise will be resolved; otherwise, the promise will be
// rejected.
validateStatus: function (status) {
  return status >= 200 && status < 300; // default
}
```

You can add your custom, for allow

```
validateStatus: function (status) {
  return status >= 200 && status <= 302
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me. Microsoft set the standard for async endpoints to return 202 and 302 so sometimes you can't just randomly change the the success status code to 200.

Answer (score 2):

If you want simply to get a response with the created resource you may use `200 Success` or `201 Created` status.
If you want to process `302 Found` somehow, you should create your own handler in `catch()` section and also send `Location` header because status `302 Found` means:

> "The content you were looking for exists but in a different location"

For more info on this topic regarding axios you can read [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/396#issuecomment-395592900).

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue.

**Try with this example:**

```
result = await axios.get(url, {
            validateStatus: function (status) {
                // if this function returns true, exception is not thrown, so
                // in simplest case just return true to handle status checks externally.
                return true;
            }
        });


if (result.status === 302) {
   // GET YOUR RESPONSE HERE
   console.log(result.data);
}
```

REf: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67904677/12382178