# How to make axios not to throw an exception when HTTP 302 is encountered, but return the AxiosResponse with it?

Tags: node.js, axios

I have an axios code that calls an endpoint which returns 302 and a `Location:` header. I am writing a test which should evaluate method response and confirm the correct (HTTP 302) response as well as check `Location:` URL contents.

So I have a test code (Jest)

```
   let axiosReply = await axios.get(this.redirectUrl, {
       maxRedirects: 0 // do not follow redirects...
   });
   expect(axiosReply.status).toBe(302);
   // some checks of header Location: follow
```

however, axios throws an error:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 302

    at createError (C:\<my project folder>\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (C:\<my project folder>\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\<my project folder>\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:260:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1184:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

How can I configure Axios just to return the reply and do not throw an error?

Comment: Why not `try` and `catch` the error?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that would be my second option, but I do not understand why axios can't just return the reply in AxiosResponse object, as it is easily possible to fill the object with the data.

Comment: Because that's just not the API, `axios` rejects not resolves if the request is considered unsuccessful. There's an equal number of people complaining about the opposite behaviour with `fetch`, which resolves unless there's an actual e.g. network error. You could look at https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order not to `throw`, use `valudateStatus` option:

```js
 result = await axios.get(this.url, {
            validateStatus: function (status) {
                // if this function returns true, exception is not thrown, so
                // in simplest case just return true to handle status checks externally.
                return true;
            }
        });


if (result.status === StatusCodes.FORBIDDEN) {
   // react on a 403 error in a custom way
}
```